# Installation of CentOS on external Hard Disk

Tags: linux, boot, external-hard-drive, centos-6

I installed CentOS on an external hard disk and it works correctly with one of my computers. However, when I boot CentOS from the external disk on my other computer, it throws an error: `kernel panic - not syncing attempted to kill init`.

I installed a boot loader on the external hard disk and it correctly gives me boot options, but after selecting CentOS it always gives me the kernel panic error. What could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem would seem to be that the kernel can't find the root disk - possibly because there is no support for the underlying device in the kernel.